# android - what is message queue native poll once in android?

Tags: java, android, performance, cpu, profile

I know that threads have a message queue and handlers are able to push runnables or messages to them, but when I profile my android application using Android Studio tools, there is a strange process:

> android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce

It uses the CPU more than all the other processes. What is it and how can I reduce the time that the CPU spends on it?
You can find the profiler result below.

[image]

Comment: Looks like a busy-wait. The answer is not to use polling. You didn't post any code or other information about your application.

Comment: what do you mean by busy-wait ?

Comment: @SajadNorouzi you can think of busy wait as an infinite loop waiting for some condition to be satisfied.
`while(isConditionSatisfied){ /*do something*/ }`
The issue is that `isConditionSatisfied` is probably very rarely or maybe even never satisfied causing what we refer to busy-wait. 
Note: This is an oversimplification  :D

Answer (score 85, accepted):

**Short answer:**

The `nativePollOnce` method is used to "wait" till the next `Message` becomes available. If the time spent during this call is long, your main (UI) thread has no real work to do and waits for next events to process. There's no need to worry about that.

**Explanation:**

Because the "main" thread is responsible for drawing UI and handling various events, it's `Runnable` has a loop which processes all these events.
The loop is managed by a [`Looper`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/os/Looper.java) and its job is quite straightforward: it processes all Messages in the [`MessageQueue`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/os/MessageQueue.java).

A [`Message`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/os/Message.java) is added to the queue for example in response to input events, as frame rendering callback or even your own `Handler.post` calls. Sometimes the main thread has no work to do (that is, no messages in the queue), which may happen e.g. just after finishing rendering single frame (the thread has just drawn one frame and is ready for the next one, just waits for a proper time). Two Java methods in the `MessageQueue` class are interesting to us: `Message next()` and `boolean enqueueMessage(Message, long)`. `Message next()`, as its name suggest, takes and returns the next Message from the queue. If the queue is empty (and there's nothing to return), the method calls `native void nativePollOnce(long, int)` which blocks until a new message is added. At this point you might ask how does `nativePollOnce` know when to wake up. That's a very good question. When a `Message` is added to the queue, the framework calls the `enqueueMessage` method, which not only inserts the message into the queue, but also calls `native static void nativeWake(long)`, if there's need to wake up the queue. The core magic of `nativePollOnce` and `nativeWake` happens in the [native (actually, C++) code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/libutils/Looper.cpp). Native MessageQueue utilizes a Linux system call named [`epoll`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoll), which allows to monitor a file descriptor for IO events. `nativePollOnce` calls `epoll_wait` on a certain file descriptor, whereas `nativeWake` writes to the descriptor, which is one of the IO operations, `epoll_wait` waits for. The kernel then takes out the epoll-waiting thread from the waiting state and the thread proceeds with handling the new message. If you're familiar with Java's `Object.wait()` and `Object.notify()` methods, you can imagine that `nativePollOnce` is a rough equivalent for `Object.wait()` and `nativeWake` for `Object.notify()`, except they're implemented completely differently: `nativePollOnce` uses `epoll` and `Object.wait()` uses [`futex`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futex) Linux call. It's worth noticing that neither `nativePollOnce` nor `Object.wait()` waste CPU cycles, as when a thread enters either method, it becomes disabled for thread scheduling purposes (quoting the javadoc for the `Object` class). However, some profilers may mistakenly recognize epoll-waiting (or even Object-waiting) threads as running and consuming CPU time, which is incorrect. If those methods actually wasted CPU cycles, all idle apps would use 100% of the CPU, heating and slowing down the device.

**Conclusion:**

You shouldn't worry about `nativePollOnce`. It just indicates that processing of all Messages has been finished and the thread waits for the next one. Well, that simply means you don't give too much work to your main thread ;)

Comment: If there is no message in the queue, how does `nativePollOnce` know how long to wait / when to wake up?

Comment: @Florian I've just updated my answer to give some more details (and to rectify some incorrect information in my original answer).

Comment: Thank you, that's great!

Comment: nativePollOnce() does NOT wait for the next message. That's done by the Java 'Looper' class. Instead, it internally calls the Linux epoll_wait method, which waits for some CPU cycles so that the loop doesn't cause a CPU overhead and the Android Looper doesn't result blocking.

Comment: As the main thread is duty for rendoring GUI.If there is no new messages come to queue,there is no one to wake the main thread.who still rendoring the GUI?

Comment: @linjiejun The messages instructing the main thread to do the rendering job may come from the framework (e.g. input events, etc.) or the app itself (e.g. when you schedule an animation, etc.). See the Choreographer class description for some more information (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Choreographer).

Comment: Any idea why I'm getting ANR for nativePollOnce? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71478162/anr-at-android-os-messagequeue-nativepollonce

Comment: @MarianPaździoch It's mistaken, the real ANR reason is not for nativePollOnce

Comment: If it's mistaken and that's the only information you get, what do you think might be the real issues causing such and error @twlkyao?