# Recycler view weird error

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I got an error

`09-10 10:50:32.770 9364-9364/com.sprdh.asmaulhusna A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI CallVoidMethodV called with pending exception 'java.lang.IllegalStateException' thrown in void android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(long, int):-2
09-10 10:50:32.770 9364-9364/com.sprdh.asmaulhusna A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]     in call to CallVoidMethodV
09-10 10:50:32.770 9364-9364/com.sprdh.asmaulhusna A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]     from void android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(long, int)
09-10 10:50:32.770 9364-9364/com.sprdh.asmaulhusna A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65] "main" prio=5 tid=1 Runnable
09-10 10:50:32.770 9364-9364/com.sprdh.asmaulhusna A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x75b64fb8 self=0x55b4a5c090
09-10 10:50:32.770 9364-9364/com.sprdh.asmaulhusna A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | sysTid=9364 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7facc47e80
09-10 10:50:32.770 9364-9364/com.sprdh.asmaulhusna A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | state=R schedstat=( 1507395371 53367917 863 ) utm=138 stm=12 core=4 HZ=100
09-10 10:50:32.770 9364-9364/com.sprdh.asmaulhusna A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | stack=0x7fe3fcd000-0x7fe3fcf000 stackSize=8MB
09-10 10:50:32.770 9364-9364/com.sprdh.asmaulhusna A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
09-10 10:50:32.770 9364-9364/com.sprdh.asmaulhusna A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #00 pc 000039a4  /system/lib64/libbacktrace_libc++.so (_ZN9Backtrace6UnwindEmP8ucontext+28)
09-10 10:50:32.770 9364-9364/com.sprdh.asmaulhusna A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #01 pc 0000001c  ???
09-10 10:50:32.770 9364-9364/com.sprdh.asmaulhusna A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native method)
09-10 10:50:32.770 9364-9364/com.sprdh.asmaulhusna A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
09-10 10:50:32.770 9364-9364/com.sprdh.asmaulhusna A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:122)
09-10 10:50:32.770 9364-9364/com.sprdh.asmaulhusna A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5276)
09-10 10:50:32.770 9364-9364/com.sprdh.asmaulhusna A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(Native method)
09-10 10:50:32.770 9364-9364/com.sprdh.asmaulhusna A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
09-10 10:50:32.770 9364-9364/com.sprdh.asmaulhusna A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:911)
09-10 10:50:32.770 9364-9364/com.sprdh.asmaulhusna A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:706)
09-10 10:50:32.770 9364-9364/com.sprdh.asmaulhusna A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65] 
09-10 10:50:33.070 9364-9364/com.sprdh.asmaulhusna A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:289] Runtime aborting...
09-10 10:50:33.070 9364-9364/com.sprdh.asmaulhusna A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:289] Aborting thread:
09-10 10:50:33.070 9364-9364/com.sprdh.asmaulhusna A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:289] "main" prio=5 tid=1 Native
09-10 10:50:33.070 9364-9364/com.sprdh.asmaulhusna A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x75b64fb8 self=0x55b4a5c090
09-10 10:50:33.070 9364-9364/com.sprdh.asmaulhusna A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   | sysTid=9364 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7facc47e80`

full logcat here [logcat](http://pastebin.com/A8JFb5j9)

for using Recyclerview for list out all songs in my mobile

```
public class SongsFragment extends Fragment {

private static String TAG = SongsFragment.class.getSimpleName();
private List<SongModel> songList = new ArrayList<>();
private SongsListAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_songs_fragment_main, container, false);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        // getting song list
   //        if (songList != null) {
 //            songList.clear();
 //
 //        }
    setupSongList(recyclerView);

    return view;
}

private void setupSongList(RecyclerView recyclerView) {

    ContentResolver musicResolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
    Uri musicUri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0";
    String sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";
    Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, null, selection, null, sortOrder);

    if (musicCursor != null && musicCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        //get columns
        int titleColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
        int idColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
        int artistColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
        int albumColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM);
        int albumIdColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID);
        int durationColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION);
        //add songs to list
        do {
            long thisId = musicCursor.getLong(idColumn);
            long albumId = musicCursor.getLong(albumIdColumn);
            String thisTitle = musicCursor.getString(titleColumn);
            String thisArtist = musicCursor.getString(artistColumn);
            String thisALbum = musicCursor.getString(albumColumn);
            int thisDuration = musicCursor.getInt(durationColumn);
            songList.add(new SongModel(thisId, thisTitle, thisArtist, thisALbum, albumId, thisDuration));
        }
        while (musicCursor.moveToNext());
    }

//        songList.add(new SongModel(1, "thisTitle1", "thisArtist1",       "thisALbum", 1, 1));
 //        songList.add(new SongModel(2, "thisTitle2", "thisArtist2",    "thisALbum", 2, 2));

    mAdapter = new SongsListAdapter(getActivity(), songList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}  }
```

as Fragment and

```
public class SongsListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SongsListAdapter.AllSongsGridHolder> {

private static String TAG = SongsListAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
private List<SongModel> allSongsList;
private Context mContext;

public SongsListAdapter(Activity context, List<SongModel> allSongsList) {
    this.allSongsList = allSongsList;
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public AllSongsGridHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_row_item_song, parent, false);
    return new AllSongsGridHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(AllSongsGridHolder holder, int position) {
    SongModel model = allSongsList.get(position);
    holder.artist.setText(model.getArtist());
    holder.title.setText(model.getTitle());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return allSongsList.size();
}

public class AllSongsGridHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    protected TextView title, artist;
    protected ImageView albumArt;

    public AllSongsGridHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.song_title);
        this.artist = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.song_artist);
        this.albumArt = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.albumArt);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    }
}  }
```

and

```
public class SongModel {

private long songId;
private String title;
private String artist;
private String album;
private long albumId;
private int duration;
private int year;

public SongModel(long songID, String songTitle, String songArtist, String songAlbum, long songalbumId, int songDuration) {
    this.songId = songID;
    this.title = songTitle;
    this.artist = songArtist;
    this.album = songAlbum;
    this.albumId = songalbumId;
    this.duration = songDuration;
}

public long getSongId() {
    return songId;
}

public void setSongId(long songId) {
    this.songId = songId;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getArtist() {
    return artist;
}

public void setArtist(String artist) {
    this.artist = artist;
}

public String getAlbum() {
    return album;
}

public void setAlbum(String album) {
    this.album = album;
}

public long getAlbumId() {
    return albumId;
}

public void setAlbumId(long albumId) {
    this.albumId = albumId;
}

public int getDuration() {
    return duration;
}

public void setDuration(int duration) {
    this.duration = duration;
}

public int getYear() {
    return year;
}

public void setYear(int year) {
    this.year = year;
}
}
```

if i use this, there is no error

```
      //for test
  songList.add(new SongModel(1, "thisTitle1", "thisArtist1",         "thisALbum", 1, 1));
       songList.add(new SongModel(2, "thisTitle2", "thisArtist2",    "thisALbum", 2, 2));
```

can anyone suggest what this is ? or any better way to do this

Comment: how much 'songList' size? according this thread [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38818642/android-what-is-message-queue-native-poll-once-in-android) it's might be caused the size is too much.

Comment: what support library version are you using ?

Comment: If the data set is too big, try using a cursor adapter. Also, if you are going to load the whole Cursor into a List of Objects, close it afterwards. I use:

Comment: if(cursor != null) { if (cursor.moveToFirst(){ do{ //stuff; } while (cursor.moveToNext()) } cursor.close()}

Comment: @AmitVaghela i use  support library version 24.2.0

Comment: okay. try version 23.2.1. and check

Comment: not working......