# Retrofit call, blocked in MessageQueue

Tags: android, retrofit, android-room, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

I would like to have a system to call API (Retrofit) with cache (in Room), with just coroutines (without LiveData and NetworkBoundResource).

So worflow is:

- Check data in db
- if present show it
- if not:

1. Call API
2. Save data in db
3. show data

Problem app blocked in "Call API" step, here the stack

> nativePollOnce:-1, MessageQueue (android.os)  next:326, MessageQueue
> (android.os) loop:160, Looper (android.os) main:6669, ActivityThread
> (android.app) invoke:-1, Method (java.lang.reflect) run:493,
> RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller (com.android.internal.os) main:858,
> ZygoteInit (com.android.internal.os)

Retrofit service:

```
interface ProductService {
    @GET("products")
    suspend fun getProducts(): Response<List<Product>>
}
```

DAO Room:

```
@Dao
interface ProductDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Product ORDER BY price")
    suspend fun getProducts(): List<Product>

    @Transaction
    @Insert(entity = Product::class)
    suspend fun insertProducts(products: List<Product>)
}
```

My fragment:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    productService = createProductService()
    productDao = MyDatabase.getDatabase(requireContext()).productDao()
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
        getProducts()
    }
}

private suspend fun getProducts() {
    progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    recyclerViewProducts.visibility = View.GONE
    
    var products = withContext(Dispatchers.IO){ productDao.getProducts() }

    if(products.isEmpty()) {

        val response = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { productService.getProducts() }
        if(response.isSuccessful && response.body() != null) {
            products = response.body()!!
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { productDao.insertProducts(products) }
        }
    }

    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
        progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
        recyclerViewProducts.visibility = View.VISIBLE

        recyclerViewProducts.apply {
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
            // set the custom adapter to the RecyclerView
            adapter = ProductsAdapter(products, this@ListProductFragment)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not clean architecture. You should have a Database layer (that you have) and a Repository and a Viewmodel. So when framgnet is created calls viewmodel to observe data from repository that also observe data from Db. If data from db is empty then it creates the api call in a coroutine scope and in the same thread it saves data to DB. So automatically viewmodel gets informed for new data

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using MVVM Design Pattern. You must do what you want in the repository pattern.

> The repository pattern is a design pattern that isolates data sources
> from the rest of the app. A repository mediates between data sources
> (such as persistent models, web services, and caches) and the rest of
> the app. The diagram below shows how app components such as activities
> that use LiveData might interact with data sources by way of a
> repository. To implement a repository, you use a repository class,
> such as the VideosRepository class that you create in the next task.
> The repository class isolates the data sources from the rest of the
> app and provides a clean API for data access to the rest of the app.
> Using a repository class is a recommended best practice for code
> separation and architecture. Advantages of using a repository. A
> repository module handles data operations and allows you to use
> multiple backends. In a typical real-world app, the repository
> implements the logic for deciding whether to fetch data from a network
> or use results that are cached in a local database. This helps make
> your code modular and testable. You can easily mock up the repository
> and test the rest of the code.

[image: MVVM Design Pattern]

I suggest you check it out for the error code.

[Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38818642/android-what-is-message-queue-native-poll-once-in-android)