# ANR at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce

Tags: android, firebase, performance, android-anr-dialog, android-looper

We are seeing this ANR in different parts of our app.
Wanted to understand what causes this ANR?

```
main (native): tid=1 systid=31940
#00 pc 0x5431c libc.so 
#01 pc 0x1313a5 libart.so 
#02 pc 0x2ab05b libart.so 
#03 pc 0x3659 libnativehelper.so 
#04 pc 0x9dee9 libandroid_runtime.so 
#05 pc 0x65c45 libgui.so 
#06 pc 0x11dcd libutils.so 
#07 pc 0x11abf libutils.so 
#08 pc 0xbcc7d libandroid_runtime.so 
       at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:339)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:199)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8276)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:612)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
```

This is what firebase has to say about this ANR -

> This thread was idle when the ANR occurred. We don't have sufficient
> information to determine the root cause.

Comment: Happened yesterday with me too with Android 11 and various Devices including mainly Samsung and Motorola.

Comment: @Harminder did you get any solution?

Comment: @sumitsingh not yet

Comment: @HarminderSingh Do you have webviews in your app? We are experiencing this ANRs too and all of them are in webview.

Comment: @HarminderSingh which @react-native-firebase/app version are you using? Did you try upgrading it?

Comment: Hi, any solutions yet?

Comment: Any Solutions yet?

Comment: Getting a lot of ANR only on Samsung Android 11 devices.
It seems to be linked with Firebase versions, because it happened just after I upgraded Firebase-bom from 28.4.2 to 29.3.1. 
There was 0 ANR before that change. And all ANR stacktraces are unusable, it's happening randomly when using the app.

Comment: Looked into this a little, it looks like firebase only started reporting ANRs in [28.4.3](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#crashlytics_v18-2-4)

Comment: I'm seeing it mostly in Android 12 (98%) and it's exclusively Asus devices, mostly ZenFone.

Comment: I find these ANRs in the Crashlytics of my flutter app as well.

Comment: @HarminderSingh did you get any solution?

Comment: i am also getting these anr , 91% android 11 and 9% on android 12.
were you able to find any solution ?

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/230950647

Comment: @TehleelMir not yet

Comment: @HarisAli no solution yet

Comment: @AyushGupta it's an android app. We not using react native in it

Comment: any temporary solution?

Comment: Facing only if app is in the background

Comment: @HarminderSingh do you found any solutions yet ?

Comment: Firebase version unrelated. After I completely removed Firebase from the project the issue still recorded in Google Play Console. The reason someone may think that this caused by Firebase update is because Firebase just recently start recording ANR. Older version of Firebase simple doesn't record it, but check in Google Play console and you'll find the ANR there.

Answer (score 24):

**NativePollOnce:**

It appears when the CPU is waiting for a new task/message.

**Reasons:**

1. ANR may occur if BroadCast Receiver hasn’t finished execution within 10 Seconds.
2. No response to an input event within 5 Seconds
3. ANR may be caused when the app tries to show a dialog by mistake but the call is not from the main thread. (Note: verify all calls of UI View from UI thread)
4. It may occur due to memory leaks.
5. Handler.postDelayed may create an issue
6. This type of crash is commonly seen, when the stack dump takes place, some app’s stack trace could be dumped for a long after the actual ANR time
7. It may occur on SCREEN_ON BROADCAST and google ads are using SCREEN_ON BROADCAST.
8. It may occur during the Garbage collection process (by
   Ezequiel Adrian comment)

**Ways to collect ANRs:**

1. WatchDog
2. Catching Native SIGQUIT
3. ApplicationExitInfo (used by crashalytics)
4. Collect from Google Play Console
5. Firebase (firebase only collect from android 11 and above)

**Challenges in Solving ANR:**

Demystifying the ANRs Puzzle. [Link](https://www.amanjeet.me/demystifying-the-anrs-puzzle/)

**Solutions:**

1. Optimize initialization and Ad Loading. [Link](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/optimize-initialization)
2. If you are using Media then release it in IO Thread
3. Find memory leaks to track down using a leak canary or Android
   profiler
4. Downgrade firebase to 28.4.2 (It will not collect ANR but it does not mean that it cannot occur)
5. Verify all calls of UI View from the UI thread
6. More Information from [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/230950647?pli=1)
7. More Info [Stack Ans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38839647/15005298)
8. Reduced the usage of Static(java) or companion object(kotlin)'s, properties, and classes

Comment: Please add to the ANR causes: Garbage collection process.

Answer (score 8):

Facing the same issue - I've read that it related to Admob or unity ads and there is an open thread for google : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/230950647?pli=1

Answer (score 3):

On the latest release of **Cloud Messaging** dependencies *v23.0.7* Firebase Mention that this release might reduce the ANR. here is his words mentioned in its [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#messaging_v23-0-7).

> Message broadcasts now finish immediately after binding to the service. This change should reduce the chance of ANRs

Comment: Unfortunately we're still seeing ANRs with v23.0.7.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was an error in the firebase cloud messaging lib. The bug was fixed in the latest version 23.1.1, which was released on 12/8/2022.

https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#messaging_v23-1-1

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Didn't work for me. Still getting ANRs

Comment: @miq0717 have you been able to fix this ANR?

Answer (score 1):

**A possible reason: The UI thread was blocked by sync barrier.**

If `MessageQueue` of the UI thread has a sync barrier, all messages will be blocked (except asynchronous ones) until the sync barrier removed.

**What will cause this issue?**

If you invalidate your view in a Non-UI thread, you may get this issue.

**Why?**

```java
// View.java
public void invalidate() {
    invalidate(true);
}
public void invalidate(boolean invalidateCache) {
    invalidateInternal(...);
}
void invalidateInternal(...) {
    final ViewParent p = mParent;
    p.invalidateChild(this, damage);
}

// ViewGroup.java
public final void invalidateChild(View child, final Rect dirty) {
    onDescendantInvalidated(child, child);
}

public void onDescendantInvalidated(@NonNull View child, @NonNull View target) {
    //...
    if (mParent != null) {
        mParent.onDescendantInvalidated(this, target);
    }
}
```

`ViewRootImpl` is the top-most `ViewParent`:

```java
public void onDescendantInvalidated(@NonNull View child, @NonNull View descendant) {
    // TODO: Re-enable after camera is fixed or consider targetSdk checking this
    // checkThread();
    invalidate();
}
void invalidate() {
    scheduleTraversals();
}
void scheduleTraversals() {
    if (!mTraversalScheduled) {
        mTraversalScheduled = true;
        mTraversalBarrier = mHandler.getLooper().getQueue().postSyncBarrier();
    }
}

void unscheduleTraversals() {
    if (mTraversalScheduled) {
        mTraversalScheduled = false;
        mHandler.getLooper().getQueue().removeSyncBarrier(mTraversalBarrier);
    }
}

void doTraversal() {
    if (mTraversalScheduled) {
        mTraversalScheduled = false;
        mHandler.getLooper().getQueue().removeSyncBarrier(mTraversalBarrier);
}
```

> Note the `postSyncBarrier` and `removeSyncBarrier` in the snippet above

Here in `onDescendantInvalidated` of `ViewRootImpl`, **it didn't check if it's in UI thread.**

So if you `invalidate` your view in a non-ui thread occasionally, you may leave a sync barrier in the message queue without being removed later and then you will get this issue.

**Do I `invalidate` my view off ui thread?**

In my case, I provide `BitmapDrawable`s to many views and then I may change the `bitmap` of the `BitmapDrawable` in a work thread. This will cause the views using the `BitmapDrawable` being invalidated in the work thread.

**How to check if any views is invalidated in non-ui thread?**

In the top-most `ViewGroup` of your view hierarchy, override `onDescendantInvalidated`:

```java
override fun onDescendantInvalidated(child: View, target: View) {
    super.onDescendantInvalidated(child, target)
    if (Looper.getMainLooper() != Looper.myLooper()) {
        throw RuntimeException("no ui thread")
    }
}
```

**Typical symptoms of the issue**

1. `RecyclerView` or `ListView` can be scrolled normally, but click listeners of any view will not work.
2. ANR may occurs with a low cpu overload and stack trace of the main thread contains `MessageQueue.nativePollOnce`
3. The ANR may be a `BroadcastTimeout` anr or a `ServiceTimeout` anr but is NOT a `KeyDispatchTimeout` anr