# MessageQueue.java android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce

Tags: java, android, firebase, crashlytics, google-play-console

Receiving ANR Error in Firebase which effect Crash-free statistics percentage
below attached screenshot please help

[image: 1]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [android - what is message queue native poll once in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38818642/android-what-is-message-queue-native-poll-once-in-android)

Comment: look this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/74010423/15005298

Comment: A possible reason: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77824374/4719124